# JSLink in form tag is not working from schema.xml in my SharePoint hosted app

Tags: list, jquery, list-form, jslink, sharepoint-hosted-app

In the app ,for schema here is my code from **schema.xml**

```
<Forms>
  <Form Type="NewForm" Name="{65B105CA-E7D8-4B28-8C9F-5B0DCBA7E0CA}" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" Url="NewForm.aspx" Default="TRUE" FormID="0" JSLink="~site/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js | ~site/Scripts/FieldToHide.js"/>
  <Form Type="EditForm" Name="{DA80DF9E-85D3-4DA2-907A-414276C85F3F}" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" Url="EditForm.aspx" Default="TRUE" FormID="0" JSLink="~site/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js | ~site/Scripts/FieldToHide.js"/>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Name="{D353EFD2-8A70-4A7D-97BE-DD942733F0BC}" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" Url="DispForm.aspx" Default="TRUE" FormID="0" JSLink="~site/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js | ~site/Scripts/FieldToHide.js"/>
  <Form Type="EditForm" Name="{C969460E-54E7-4EB3-A325-FE1BEFA0056F}" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" Url="EditInfo.aspx" Default="FALSE" FormID="0" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Name="{460F5D08-1EBF-4179-97CE-7552DEABBDA1}" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" Url="AddEmployee.aspx" Default="FALSE" FormID="0" />
</Forms>
```

I am trying to apply **js** into all above pages but **jslink** from first form tag is working and others are not. Please suugest any help

Comment: Could you add the jsLink to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the white space around the pipe.  jslink is pretty finicky.